# LDAP query issue

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am looking for a ldap query which return only Organizational Unit which are direct descendent of Domain

For example: I have `ADDOMAIN01` which contains `OUSales` which has a child OU `OUAutoMobiles`. The issue is that when I search

```
(&(objectCategory=organizationalunit))
```

it returns all OUs including `OUAutomobiles`, and I want only top level OUs just `OUSales`.

Also: if I want OUs of only `OUSales` not of entire Domain, what should be the query?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

When you write a SEARCH in LDAP you give :

1. The DN of the nod where begin the search
2. The attributes you want to retreive
3. the filter ((&(objectCategory=organizationalunit))
4. The deepness of your search and HERE it's OneLevel (not `subtree`, nor `base`)

With LDIFDE.EXE it's -p option

JP

Comment: Thanx, what is LDIFDE.EXE it's -p option ?????, also if we filter with ((&(objectCategory=organizationalunit)) it will return all OUs if the DN is set to DOMAIN

Comment: LDIFDE.EXE is a tool present on Windows servers. It allow you to execute LDAP_SEARCH verbs or to import LDIF files. How do you code your search.